# Creating tables dynamically in MySql from existing table

Tags: mysql

I am creating a website and linking it to mysql database by PHP.
I have one major table that the user of the website can enter values in and I want to create tables from that big table dynamically.

For example, I have a table that has some records of schools visits, a school might appear more than once in the records so I want to have tables for each school independently which takes its  information from the big table and update its values whenever a new record is entered for that school. I am not sure if this can be done dynamically. I am kind of new to MySql, any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: create school master and post unique school names from visits into that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but its not advisable. It's better to use a single table. If you need to improve performance you can add indexes.

If you still want to do this you might want to consider [creating views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) rather than tables:

```
CREATE VIEW view_school1 AS
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln 
FROM school WHERE name = 'school1'
```

Comment: I have another question is it possible to add new fields to the view?I want to add indexes to each specific school visit.Actually the whole story why I want to do this is whenever a user searches for records for one school & after the records appear,I want to add an option to view each record separately in a specific form I thought of adding radio buttons beside each record & the selected button will show the related record by linking it to the record index.I think it is cumbersome but no other idea came to mind for how to show each record.If any have better idea I would be thankful:)

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand your requirements. Are you trying to create a [master-detail interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface)?

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear enough, mybe that's close to what i need this is the first time i hear about this am kind of begenner, let me say it again when the user searches for a specific school name all records for it will appear then i want him lets say click on one record then that record details will appear on a different page as a report that can be printed of that visit

Comment: You absolutely do *not* need separate tables or views to achieve that. It's just simple queries.